# Wordpress category hierarchy - sub category but parent permalink

Tags: wordpress, blogs, categories, hierarchy

I have a Wordpress blog. There are more categories. Category hierarchy like below.

Technology News

- Mobile News
- Internet News

...

in address bar it shown like

```
site.com/category/technology-news/internet-news
```

but I want to see at address bar like below

```
site.com/category/internet-news
```

so how can I show a sub category as parent category. Remember it's still a sub category actually.

Answer (score 0):

Go into Settings -> Permalinks. Select "Custom Structure" and paste this line in.

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

Next, open your themes functions.php file and drop in the following code.

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'remove_parent_cats_from_link', 10, 3 );
function remove_parent_cats_from_link( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {

    $cats = get_the_category( $post->ID );
    if ( $cats ) {
        usort( $cats, '_usort_terms_by_ID' );
        $category = $cats[0]->slug;

        if ( $parent = $cats[0]->parent ) {
            $parentcats = get_category_parents( $parent, false, '/', true );
            $permalink = str_replace( $parentcats, '', $permalink );
        }
    }

    return $permalink;

}
```